# Send a string through email in VBScript

Tags: .net, email, vbscript, gmail

I am trying to make me a very basic application in VBScript that can send an email through gmail to me. It collects input from an input box, and I want the input box to create a string that I will be able to send. Here's my working code:

```
Messagebody=InputBox("Enter Steam Username:")
WScript.Echo Messagebody

EmailSubject = "Sending Email by CDO"
EmailBody = "This is the body of a message sent via" & vbCRLF & _
"a CDO.Message object using SMTP authentication ,with port 465."

Const EmailFrom = "from@gmail.com"
Const EmailFromName = "Singing Unicorn"
Const EmailTo = "to@gmail.com"
Const SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
Const SMTPLogon = "login@gmail.com"
Const SMTPPassword = "password"
Const SMTPSSL = True
Const SMTPPort = 465

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1    'Send message using local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2  'Send the message using SMTP over TCP/IP networking.

Const cdoAnonymous = 0  ' No authentication
Const cdoBasic = 1  ' BASIC clear text authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2   ' NTLM, Microsoft proprietary authentication

' First, create the message

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = EmailSubject
objMessage.From = """" & EmailFromName & """ <" & EmailFrom & ">"
objMessage.To = EmailTo
objMessage.TextBody = EmailBody

' Second, configure the server

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = SMTPLogon

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = SMTPPassword

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SMTPPort

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = SMTPSSL

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
'Now send the message!
On Error Resume Next
objMessage.Send

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Description,16,"Error Sending Mail"
Else 
MsgBox "Mail was successfully sent !",64,"Information"
End If
```

Please give me some help to do it. Very appreciated.

Comment: I hope the credentials are fake !! Otherwise edit your question, now !!
But simply add `MessageBody` to `EmailBody` ? If it's the answer you need, you should study a little what you're doing. Example: `EmailBody = "your text" & messageBody & "other text"`

Comment: THANKS! YOU GAVE ME THE ANSWER I NEEDED! Yeah I know nothing about vbs I took various premade codes.

Comment: Btw what are credentials?

Comment: User "********@gmail.com" and password "!M**iM**33**" ! Are they real? if so, delete them !!

Comment: Yes, change your password immediately. Removing them after the fact won't help, as threads are archived my multiple sources.

Comment: @Baro deleting them changes nothing, they will still be in the revision history.

Comment: Changed my password. Damn I was dumb. Baro put your answer, fixed my problem. Thanks Leigh, I will slowly but surely get used to the website, yes I am new. Thanks guys!

Comment: Oh and btw thanks for everyone that saw this and didn't steal my gmail account. 2 subscribers on youtube is quite a lot to lose.

Answer (score -1):

I hope the credentials are fake !! Otherwise edit your question, now !! But simply add MessageBody to EmailBody ? If it's the answer you need, you should study a little what you're doing. Example: EmailBody = "your text" & messageBody & "other text" – Baro 15 mins ago

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are new to the site, it works a little differently than a discussion forum.  If someone *else* provides an answer to your question, generally it is nice to ask that person to promote their comment to an official answer  :-)

Comment: .. That way others can vote on it, and they can possibly earn a few votes. Just a little way of saying thanks for assisting.